# How to execute two Async<> calls with different result types in parallel?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have two asynchronous operations, so I have these functions:

```
// Returs Async<Person>
let GetPerson =
  ...

// Returs Async<Address>
let GetAddress =
  ...
```

What is the idiomatic way to execute them in parallel and get their results?

My starting point is this approach.

```
let MyFunc = async {
    let! person = GetPerson()
    let! address = GetAddress()
    ...
  }
```

This works, but this runs the two operations sequentially.

I also tried this (sort of based on my C# experience).

```
let MyFunc = async {
    let personA = GetPerson()
    let addressA = GetAddress()
    let! person = personA
    let! address = addressA
    ...
  }
```

But it doesn't work, it also runs the two operations sequentially.

What most of the documentation says is to use `Async.Parallel` with a sequence, but the problem is that the result type of the two operations are different, so I cannot put them in a sequence.

```
let MyFunc = async {
    let personA = GetPerson()
    let addressA = GetAddress()

    [personA; addressA]
    |> Async.Parallel
    ...
  }
```

This gives a compilation error, because the two values have different types. (And also, with this syntax, how could I get the actual results?)

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to start both computations using `Async.StartAsChild` and then wait for their completion using a second `let!`:

```
let MyFunc = async {
    let! personWork = GetPerson() |> Async.StartChild
    let! addressWork = GetAddress() |> Async.StartChild
    let! person = personWork
    let! address = addressWork
    // (...)
  }
```

Just calling `GetPerson` does not actually start the work - unlike in C# where tasks are created started, F# workflows are just descriptions of the work to be done, so they need to be started explicitly. The `Async.StartChild` operation gives you a workflow that starts the work and returns another workflow that can be used for wait for its completion.

Comment: IF `GetPerson` and `GetAddress` are also async primitives, they by convention should they also be prefixed with async. i.e. `asyncGetPerson` and `asyncGetAddress` ?

Comment: That is certainly the case for F# library functions (`AsyncGetResponse` vs. `GetResponse`). I'd follow this pattern if I had both synchronous and asynchronous versions, but probably not when writing code that only has asynchronous version.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I noticed that for ``Async.Merge`` on your joinads blog you used ``Async.Parallel`` instead of this 'idiomatic' approach. I'm curious about why did you use such approach, is it more efficient for a specific scenario?

Comment: @Gustavo: Async.Parallel only works for async jobs that return the same type, but this S.O. question is about differing types

Comment: @knocte I know, but if you have a look at the code I was referring you'll see it uses boxing to allow the types to differ.

Comment: can you add a link?